# Gauge fixing function in the quantization of gauge field theory

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory

A gauge  fixing  function in the process of quantization of a gauge field is  the function $f: M \rightarrow  \mathfrak{g}$ ,  where  $M$ is the space of fields  and $\mathfrak{g}$ is the Lie algebra  of the gauge group $G$.

Why is the right side $\mathfrak{g}$ ? How to explain this function?

Comment: Because the gauge field take values in *g*?

Comment: The gauge field is a Lie algebra valued 1-form, so you have to take values there.